# How can I get the billing for a VM Instance in GCP?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a project in `Google Cloud`, where I have multiple instances running, and I have a billing account for the organisation. But I want to make a VM instance, say `vm-01` for couple of hours then it will be deleted. I want to get the exact cost that `vm-01` incurred during it's period using the API calls. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not possible using the [Google Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis). You can try the workaround as advised by [kkpoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3113419/kkpoon)

Answer (score 1):

In your GCP Web Console,

1. go to **Billing page**
2. go to **Billing export** section
3. you could either export the detail billing to BigQuery or File
4. you could search the billing item in the export

   - https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples
   - https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file

And suggest you to use [Label](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) to label the resource, e.g. Compute Engine, for better resource management.